# is DBNull vs. DBNull.Value.Equals()

Tags: c#, dbnull

I am curious what are the pros and cons of using `if(some_value is DBNull)` versus `if(DBNull.Value.Equals(some_value))`.
Personally i prefer `if(some_value is DBNull)` because i find it more readable.
I know Microsoft recommends using `if(DBNull.Value.Equals(some_value))` according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: it is not duplicate, this question is different than that one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for the `DBNull.Value.Equals` way.

Why?

Beacuse `is` will check the type against equality. It has to look up the left hand type and match that against the right hand type which it also has to look up. After that it can compare the types, most likely by checking for reference equality.

That would be less efficient than just checking reference equality, which `DBNull.Value.Equals` does. Since there is just once instance of `DBNull.Value`, this check is very accurate and very fast.

Comment: And using `==` or `!=` is even better and faster :)

Comment: Which would be the same as `Equals` if I am correct @IvanStoev Both check for reference equality.

Comment: Well, not exacly. It will be `ReferenceEquals`, i.e. simple IL instruction.

Comment: Aside from performance are there any differences in the result of the two operations? I understand they are very different, but i could not think of an example when they give different results, since DBNull is sealed.

Answer (score 2):

`value is DBNull` actually checks whether `value` is an instance of the `DBNull` class, while `value == DBNull.Value` actually performs a reference comparison between `value` and the only instance of the singleton class `DBNull`.

The `value is DBNull` checks whether `value` is an instance of `DBNull`, which is only possible if `value == DBNull.Value`, since `DBNull` is a singleton.

The advantage of using `value == DBNull.Value` is that it does a direct reference comparison which will be more efficient than determining the types for the `is DBNull` comparison.

Answer (score 0):

`some_value is DbNull` : checks the **type** of some_value against type of `DBNull`. This could be used if you could either instantiate an instance of `DBNull` OR inherit from it. But no, this class has private constructors and is sealed.

`DBNull.Value.Equals(some_value)`: checks **value** of some_value against the value represented by `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: No pros and cons. Both compare totally different things - type in one case and value in the other. Horses for courses....

Comment: In general, you are right. But in the DbNull case the result is the same: DbNull.Value is the only possible value of type DbNull.

Comment: Can you elaborate how the results is same? Both compare two different things - one compares type and other the value.

Comment: @VijayGill It's a Singleton, so there is only one instance of that type `DBNull.Value`.  So if the type is the same then the reference will also be the same.  And of course if the references are equal then the types are too.

Comment: @VijayGill Since `DBNull` is a singleton and `DBNull.Value` is the only instance of `DBNull`, `value is DBNull` is only possible if `value == DBNull.Value` and vice versa.

Comment: On what basis is it assumed that "some_value" in this question is an instance of DBNull?

Comment: @VijayGill That's not the assumption. It is the question. You want to find out whether `some_value` is an instance of `DBNull`. And as `DBNull` is a singleton with its sole instance `DBNull.Value`, `is DBNull` and `== DBNull.Value` both do exactly the same thing in the end, but `== DBNull.Value` does it more efficiently.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - that I understand, I just got caught-up in **my** assumption that "some_value" could be anything. Thanks for clearing it out.