# ExecuteNonQuery always returns -1 even when the SQL statement is correct

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, executenonquery

I'm using the following function to calculate sum qty value of given item code(VB.NET, SQL Server, SQL). I do not get any errors but the returned value by the function is always `-1`. The data is available in the table(Screenshot attached). I think, something is missing in my code but cant figure it out. Any advice will be highly appreciated.

```vb
Public Function findPurchaseQty(ByVal itCode As String, ByVal fromDate As DateTime, toDate As DateTime) As Double
    Dim sql = "SELECT sum(purchase_qty) FROM TB_STOCK WHERE it_code = @it_code AND added_date >= @added_date_start AND added_date < @added_date_end"
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)

    With command.Parameters
        .Add("@it_code", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = itCode
        .Add("@added_date_start", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fromDate
        .Add("@added_date_end", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = toDate
    End With

    Dim purchaseTotal As Double = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Return purchaseTotal
End Function
```

I execute the function for testing as follows but later plan to take values from date time picker,

```vb
Dim fromDate As DateTime = "2020-07-20 00:00:00"
Dim toDate As DateTime = "2020-07-22 23:59:59"
Dim itCode As String = "0001"
MsgBox(findPurchaseQty(itCode, fromDate, toDate))
```

[image: Data table]

Comment: You're calling the wrong method. `ExecuteNonQuery` doesn't return anything from a result set of the query you've run. I suspect you were looking for `ExecuteScalar`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the name already says [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery) is not the right method for a `SELECT` as it returns the number of rows affected, not the result of the `SELECT`-Query.

What you're looking for is [`ExecuteScalar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar)

As `ExecuteScalar` returns an `Object` you have to cast the result to a `Double`.

```vb
Dim purchaseTotal As Double = DirectCast(command.ExecuteScalar(), Double)
```

---

As mentioned in comments, it is a good idea to check if `ExecuteScalar()` returns a number instead of `DBNull.Value`, to prevent `DirectCast` from failing.

```vb
Dim result As Object = command.ExecuteScalar()
Dim purchaseTotal As Double
If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(result) Then
    purchaseTotal = DirectCast(result, Double)
End If
```

Comment: It would be best to check if command.ExecuteScalar() returned Nothing (i.e. no result) before casting.

Comment: Thanks I only noticed it now.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, or put a Try/Catch around...SQL operations could fail because of many reasons, like a lost connection or invalid parameter values...

Comment: @MatSnow, exception handling is a different subject. If `ExecuteScalar` returns then the operation hasn't failed. We shouldn't have to include exception handling in every answer we provide for any question.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I don't think that `ExecuteScalar` can return `Nothing` in the sense that you mean it. In the case of a `Double` result, `Nothing` would actually mean a result of 0.0. If there was no data then the result would be `DBNull.Value`, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I tried it. If `DirectCast` is used as shown in the first part of this answer and the `SELECT` query does not return anything, a System.NullReferenceException is raised.

Comment: It states in the documentation for [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) "Returns Object The first column of the first row in the result set, or a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the result set is empty. Returns a maximum of 2033 characters."

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks, you're right. I forgot to set `Option Strict On` in my test. I've edited my answer and use now `DBNull.Value.Equals()`, which is the recommended way.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38373783/is-dbnull-vs-dbnull-value-equals

Comment: @MatSnow That still doesn't work: it is `Nothing`, not `DbNull.Value`. The latter is a legitimate return value, the former is no value returned.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It works in this case, as the sql `SUM` function leads to the result `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: @MatSnow Ah, yes, that's another thing to watch out for, I see. Do you want to add something to your answer to explain that, in case someone refers to this Q&A and, like me, doesn't spot that and should use the check for Is Nothing?

Comment: Not that `If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(result) Then` is specifically wrong but I would tend to use `If result IsNot DBNull.Value Then`.